# Can I edit the inherited properties of an "Class id" via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I have a site running on Bootstrap.

My header contains a container. Also, when I scroll the page #header.header-scrolled is added as class. This is something I want. However, I want the transparency feature to be equal in both cases. As the container is a feature of the Header when I slide it, it doesn't remove with the removeClass function. Therefore, a backdrop-filter is used twice in the part where the container is.

```
  header {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  top: 20px;
}

#header .header-container {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);

}

#header.header-scrolled {
  top: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

I cannot remove the .header-container in this function.

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
    } else {
      $('#header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
    }
  });
```

Also I am using this as HTML:

```
 <header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header-container d-flex align-items-center">
```

As a result, when the page is scrolled, the container part becomes two-layered.

[Backdrop-filter applied twice due to the feature inherited to the header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOShV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try managing this case squarely with CSS... By adding a [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class.

```
#header:not(.header-scrolled) .header-container {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```